# Data set and collation in a Mysql DB

Tags: mysql, database, collation, charset

I created a database in Mysql for a record room mgt system using Sinhala character set. But when I export that database file and use it in another database(by importing) all the characters show as symbols(as I think Latin charset)
Then I changed the character set of each table into utf8 format, but It's still displaying the same.
How can I convert all the records I have entered(around 3500 records) into utf8mb4_general_ci format?

I changed the charset into utfmb4 but It didn't convert the existing records in my database

Comment: How did you change the character set? I.e. can you show an example `ALTER TABLE` statement?

Comment: ALTER DATABASE recordroom CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_sinhala_ci;
ALTER TABLE records CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_sinhala_ci;

Comment: Okay, it appears you converted the data to utf8mb4 character set correctly. Different collations of the same character set do not change the character encodings, so the data should display the same whether the columns are defined with collation utf8mb4_general_ci or utf8mb4_sinhala_ci.

Comment: In what context are you seeing the characters display incorrectly? In a web page? Query tool? MySQL Workbench GUI?

Comment: In the web page

Comment: It's possible the code for your web page is not preserving the utf8 character encoding properly. I would recommend try to confirm if the data is encoded properly in the database: test a query in the mysql query tool (e.g. I would use the command-line `mysql` client). This bypasses the web code.

Comment: We need to see more details -- `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` (for a sample), hex dump of a piece of any file being used for transfer.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored